# Редактирование меню на wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, html

Какой файл отвечает за формирование меню на wordpress? Если еще короче изложить вопрос и понятней, то хочу на вордпрес реализовать точно такое же меню как [тут](http://www.sitel.com/)

Answer (score 1):

> какой файл отвечает за формирование меню на wordpress?

Никакой.

Само форматирование меню осуществляется с помощью пары хуков: `get_pages` предоставляет доступ к массиву страниц, поднятому из БД (поэтому лучше туда не лезть, он слишком низкоуровневый и может дать побочный эффект в других местах) и `wp_list_pages`, который даст доступ к уже сформированному html. Соответственно, надо прицепиться ко второму и изменить вывод так, как хочется:

```
//functions.php
function addExtraMenuItem($menu)
{
    return $menu.'<li>I\'m an extra item!</li>';
}
add_filter('wp_list_pages', 'addExtraMenuItem');
```

Comment: не нашел данную и даже похожую функцию в этом файле, где можно поменять вывод меню так как это нужно?

Comment: > не нашел данную и даже похожую функцию в этом файле

потому что ее надо написать самому

> где можно поменять вывод меню так как это нужно?

в этой функции (хуке)

http://www.websoldier.ru/chto-takoe-xuki-wordpress-i-kak-ix-ispolzovat.html
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks

Comment: теперь не совсем понимаю зачем точкой склеиваем это выражение $menu.'<li>I\'m an extra item!</li>'; и что передается вв переменной $menu. мое меню планируется быть многоуровненвым

Comment: @privetsh готовый html-код менюшки

Comment: я просто хочу для себя понимать процесс работы функции, если можно так выразиться, а каким образом будут подставляться ссылки на страницы и подписи их? через %s ?
например
<ul><li><a href='%s'>%s</a></li></ul> я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @privetsh, внутри этого хука - никак, вордпресс уже отработал и предоставил готовый html, все остальные изменения производятся "руками", хоть через `sprintf`, хоть через конкатенацию, хоть еще как. Если влезть в `get_pages`, то, насколько помню, вордпресс будет использовать что-то похожее, только с воможностью вставки подменю в `<li>` и использование `get_permalink()` для создания ссылок (т.е. подсунуть фальшивую страницу с прописанным guid (фиксированный url в wp) не получится).

Comment: бл-н для меня это марсианский язык, мне просто нужно сделать такое же меню как на сайте ссылку которого я приводил выше

Comment: помоему бессмысленный ответ, вопрос звучит как "редактирование меню" а не как "добавление к существующему меню своих ссылок". "Никакой." - Если никакой, то почему у меня есть файл menu.php?